# Groovy Spock Test is failing when using StepVerifier for a simple Service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am attempting to test my service ProductService, but it is failing indicating that the assert is a MonoJust instead of the Product I'm expecting. I don't know why test is failing with the issue. I would appreciate some help in resolving this problem

Here is my repository, service and test code below

```java
           class Product  {
                
                 String name
                 String productCode
                 int quantity
                 double price
            }


           interface ProductRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Product, Long> {

           }

           class ProductService {
                 ProductRepository productRepository;
                 
                 ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
                  this.productRepository = productRepository
                 }

                 Mono<Product> saveProduct(Mono<Product> product){
                  return  product.flatMap(_product -> productRepository.save(_product));
               }
            }
```

```java
            import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
            import reactor.test.StepVerifier
            import spock.lang.Specification
            
            import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
            
            class ProductServiceSpec extends Specification{
                
                ProductRepository productRepository = Mock()
                ProductService productService = new ProductService(productRepository)
            
                def "should save a product to database"() {
                    given:
                    def product = new Product("T-Shirt", "LG-TSHRT", 1220, 7.77)
                    def productMono = Mono.just(product)
                    productMono.flatMap {productRepository.save(it) } >> productMono
            
                    when:
                    Mono<Product> productResult = productService.saveProduct(productMono)
            
                    then:
                    StepVerifier.create(productResult)
                            .expectNext(config)
                            .assertNext(_product -> {
                                assertThat(_product.getName()).isEqualTo("T-Shirt")
                            })
                            .expectComplete()
                            .verify()
                }
            }
```

The problem is that after the StepVerifier.create, the resulting object in assertNext is a MonoJust so it does not find the method getName().
I tried using expectNext(), consumeNextWith() but all fail with verify() is a MonoJust. I'm really perplexed by this as the method returns a Mono as seen from Intellij's intellisense and I expected StepVerifier.create(productResult) to unwrap the mono

Here is the exception:

```java
StepVerifier .create(productResult) .assertNext(product -> { assertThat(1, _product.getName()) == 'T-Shirt') ) })
.expectComplete() .verify()
|             |      |        |                                                                                                                                        |                 |
|             |      MonoJust |                                                                                                                                        |                 java.lang.AssertionError: expectation failed (failed running expectation on signal [onNext(MonoJust)] with [groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException]:
|             |               |                                                                                                                                        | 
                
No such property: getName for class: reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust)
|             |               |                                                                                                                                        |                    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.assertionError(MessageFormatter.java:115)
```

Comment: It seems there is some differences with an actual code b/c some part looks strange. Like `productMono.flatMap {productRepository.save(it) } >> productMono` seems to be from something else as it doesn't make sense here. And there is no `config` for `.expectNext(config)`. Also you have `_product` but you check `product`. And so on. Can you please make sure you have an actual code, because it's likely that you have a problem related to something not shown with code in the question.

Comment: I will modify the code, thank you

Comment: That would be really helpful. Because I guess I could answer the question since I use Spock with Reactor, but I cannot understand the question yet.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, I would have used the expectNextMateches.
Something like that

```
                    StepVerifier.create(productResult)
                        .expectNextMatches(product -> product.getName().isEqualTo("T-Shirt"))
                        .expectComplete()
                        .verify()
```

Remember that you can add more that one match using && or || operators

Comment: The problem is that after StepVerifier.create(productResult) the object resulting from the create is a MonoJust. I don't know why that is the case. When I debug the code, I see the MonoJust has the product within it

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
def productMono = Mono.just(product)
ProductRepository productRepository = Stub(ProductRepository.class)
productRepository. save(Product.class) >> productMono
ProductService productService = new ProductService(productRepository)...
```

In this case one stub is more useful that a mock.
Pleas have a look of this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spock-stub-mock-spy

Comment: The problem is not the tests setup. The test returns a Mono<Product> as I can tell from running it using the debugger. The issue is when using the StepVerifier.create() I still get a MonoJust when I call assertNext() and try to use the assertions